# How to prove that $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 2xyz$ has no solutions over the positive integers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

My strategy is proof by contradiction. 
So assume the opposite of the proof statement is true. 
I could only think of $x^2 - y^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 2xyz$ 
$=(x+y)(x-y) + y^2 + z^2 $ but I don't think that is a helpful simplification. Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: Note: you can treat this as a quadratic in $x$

Comment: Sorry there's a typo in my question.

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee I don't think this is a duplicate-I'm proving there is no solutions and the answers there don't really help me.

Comment: The accepted answer in the link shows that all solutions are (0,0,0). Therefore, it shows that there is no solution over the positive integers. There are also several other good proofs on that page, plus the one I hinted at below before I realized the question was a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint. Rearrange to get $z^2 + z(-2xy) + (x^2+y^2) = 0$. By the quadratic formula, $z = \frac{2xy \pm \sqrt{4 x^2 y^2 - 4(x^2+y^2)} }{2}$. Your proposition is true iff there are no $x$ and $y$ for which the right hand side is a positive integer.

(Edited to reflect the edit in the question)

Comment: but the problems is that I have seemed to prove the assumption true...because $\sqrt{x^2y^2-x^2-y^2} \ge 0$ is true and there are positive solutions for $x,y,z$